# .data() jQuery return datas i can't see on the HTML with collapse bootstrap component

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was doing some tests on the Collapse javascript component and i observed something weird trying to display the data attributes from the `#collapseOne` div element.

I used the bootstrap example from their website to make this test:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And i launched this code into my console:

```
JSON.stringify($('div#collapseOne').data())
```

I got `{}` which is normal siince i have no `data` attribute on this element, but if i click the second accordion, and launch again

```
JSON.stringify($('div#collapseOne').data())
```

I get `"{"collapse":null}"`, however in the console the div looks like:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">...</div>
```

So, since there is no `data-collapse` attribute, i don't understand how `.data()` can return this...?

The second behavior i don't understand is, if i click the first accordion then launch

```
JSON.stringify($('div#collapseOne').data())
```

I get this error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` on chrome and firefox is able to print

```
{"collapse":{"$element":{"0":{"jQuery191023166512553611396":4},"context":{"jQuery191023166512553611396":4},"length":1},"options":{"toggle":"collapse","parent":"#accordion2"},"$parent":{"length":1,"0":{},"context":{"jQuery191023166512553611396":1,"location":{}},"selector":"#accordion2"},"transitioning":0}}
```

I am really curious to understand where these datas are hidden since i can't see it on the HTML by inspecting the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.data()` is not a direct reflection of an elements `data` attributes. These values are interpreted by jQuery and stored internally in memory. If you manually add some data to an element, you can't retrieve it through `.attr()`.

```
$(function () {
    var element = $('#uniqueId');

    element.data('foo', 'bar');
    console.warn(element.attr('data-foo'));
    // console will warn undefined instead of 'bar' as expected

    console.error(element.data('foo'));
    // console will error 'bar' as expected

    // edit in response to a comment
    element.attr('data-baz', 'test');
    console.log(element.data('baz'));
    // console *will* log 'test'

    // manually add a data attribute to the element
    console.warn(element.data('myNewDataAttr'));
    // console *will* warn your newly added data attr

});
```

These values are also cast into what jQuery believes they are, in the case of `data-bool="true"`, the value of `$.data('bool')` will be of type `boolean` and not `string` as expected.

Comment: See also: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5
"The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)."